# Shift rows to one next columns in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe. But I want to move the 2nd and 3rd row to the right as Time values should go under time column, Exp values should go under exp column, QT values should go under QT column.

Current Table:

| Name | Date | Time | Exp | QT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VT1 | 04/16 | 4:00 | Glen | 1600 |
| VT2 | 04/16 | 4:00 | Cof | 1600 |
| VT3 | 5:00 | Sam | 1750 | NAN |
| VT4 | 7:00 | tom | 1970 | NAN |

Expected:

| Name | Date | Time | Exp | QT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VT1 | 04/16 | 4:00 | Glen | 1600 |
| VT2 | 04/16 | 4:00 | Cof | 1600 |
| VT3 | NAN | 5:00 | Sam | 1750 |
| VT4 | NAN | 7:00 | tom | 1970 |

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer below:

Select the rows which we need to move and select the columns and shift it 1 step to the left.

`df.iloc[2:,1:] = df.iloc[2:,1:].shift(1,axis=1)`

Current Table:

| Name | Date | Time | Exp | QT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VT1 | 04/16 | 4:00 | Glen | 1600 |
| VT2 | 04/16 | 4:00 | Cof | 1600 |
| VT3 | 5:00 | Sam | 1750 | NAN |
| VT4 | 7:00 | tom | 1970 | NAN |

Output:

| Name | Date | Time | Exp | QT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VT1 | 04/16 | 4:00 | Glen | 1600 |
| VT2 | 04/16 | 4:00 | Cof | 1600 |
| VT3 | NAN | 5:00 | Sam | 1750 |
| VT4 | NAN | 7:00 | tom | 1970 |